# Error - How to dynamic show/hide alert in Angular 2 based on authentication

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-ng-if

I have problem with showing/hiding alert element in few second. I want to, when I'm not authenticated, to hide in few seconds alert-danger, while I'm authenticated, I want to dynamic show alert-success in few second and hide alert-danger.

Is it possible? 
I made it with jQuery and it work in one way and give me error.

Error that show in console when alert disappears is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (app.component.ts:19)
    at HTMLDivElement.e.complete (jquery.min.js:3)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at i (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Function.r.fx.tick (jquery.min.js:3)
    at bb (jquery.min.js:3)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:265)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.js:227)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:264)
```

**App component ts file**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Auth } from './auth.service';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {


  constructor(private auth: Auth,
              private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (!this.auth.authenticated()) {
    jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('#loggedOut').fadeTo(3000, 1000).slideUp(1000, function(){
    jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('#loggedOut').slideUp(1000);
      });
    } else if (this.auth.authenticated()) {
    jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('#loggedIn').fadeTo(3000, 1000).slideUp(1000, function(){
    jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('#loggedIn').slideUp(1000);
      });
    }
  }

}
```

**App component html file**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" id="loggedIn" *ngIf="auth.authenticated()">You are logged in</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" id="loggedOut" *ngIf="!auth.authenticated()">You are not logged in</div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

[This is app.component.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL9vB.jpg)

[This is app.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S28ix.png)

Comment: ngIf does not render the component on the page at all when false, so your jquery will be unable to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can directly search for element with id 'LoggedIn' or 'LoggedOut', but as Jonathan Niu said ngIf will completely eliminate them from DOM so you can move your id up to parent

```
<div class="container" id="LoggedIn">
```

and apply your animation